# set date default ion-datetime Ionic v-2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have problem i try set the default date is today end disable day passed.
But when i set the default date is today i must convert date to string. So i can't calculator this.

Some body help me set the default date is today and calculator date. Thanks for reading my topic!

This is my code:

```js
this.startDate = new Date().toISOString();
this.minDate = new Date().toISOString();
<ion-datetime
    displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm"
    [min]="minDate"
    [(ngModel)]="startDate"
    >
 </ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 5):

From ionicv2 docs 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/

> Ionic uses the ISO 8601 datetime format for its value. The value is
>   simply a string, rather than using JavaScript's Date object.
>   Additionally, when using the ISO datetime format, it makes it easier
>   to serialize and pass within JSON objects, and sending databases a
>   standardized format which it can be easily parsed if need be.

So, you can get the ISO string date by

```
startDate: String = new Date().toISOString();
```

and use it in the view like so

```
<ion-datetime
        displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm"
        [(ngModel)]="startDate"
        >
```

If you want to disable backdated date, you can try this

```
   min="2016-10-31"
```

and also you can specify the maxDate by

```
   max="2020-12-12"
```

in your ion-datetime directive